# Angular scope.$digest inside setTimeout()

Tags: angularjs

I have found an example of using $digest() inside setTimeout() and wondering if it is a good practice to use this way:

```
setTimeout(function(){

  scope.$digest();
})
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the basic javascript functions won't be picked up by Angular. I won't say this is a good practice, because for this stuff angular has its own services, namely the `$timeout` service:

```
$timeout(function(){
    // everything in here will be picked up by angular's digest cycle
});
```

The `$scope.$digest()` is a way to manually trigger angular's digest cycle, but I cannot think of any use-case you would want this.

Even **if** you have code that occurs in native javascript, I would do it like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // do stuff that will be picked up by angular
    });
}
```

Comment: `$scope.$digest()` definitely has its use case. As opposed to `$scope.$apply()`, it triggers digest only for current scope, not for the whole hierarchy. But it is unlikely that OP supposes that.